# Set a limit to a number

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if there is a function that limits a number as an input from 0 to 1. For example if I have a number close to 0 then the result would be 0. But given a number close to infinity the result would be 1

Comment: What if it's negative?

Comment: Can't be negative because of problem definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a metric such as `z = x/(x+1)`

Answer (score 2):

What if you divide input number by the maximum number that can be stored?